# How to click on a <a href=""> using Selenium in Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on this link:

```
<a href="updating/login.php" target="_top">Login</a>
```

with Selenium using Python. l've tried finding and clicking the element by text with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
elem = rd.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login")
elem.click()
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: can you paste the url of the app?

Comment: https://itmfs1.it.siu.edu/PF/index.php

Answer (score 0):

To click on the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with text as **Login** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Login"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='updating/login.php']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='updating/login.php' and text()='Login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried your approach, but I got this error :
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ta-ph/Documents/Sites for success test/peopleFinder.py", line 13, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(rd.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='updating/login.php' and text()='Login']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\ta-ph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

`